# Each process starts from the beginning of .py file

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am new in multiprocessing. My problem is, each process starts from the beginning of .py file.
My code prints "Starting file" 3 times but it should only be printed once. Here is the output and code. Please help. Thanks.

[image]

```
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep
print("Starting file")

def worker1():  
x=1
while 1<2:
    print("worker1: "+str(x))
    x=x+1
    sleep(3)

def worker2():   
x=2
while 1<2:
    print("worker2: "+str(x))
    x=x+2
    sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Why do you think it should only be printed once? You do have three processes after all.

Comment: But there is no "print" statement in the target of P1 and p2. Because I am new in python so I can't understand the logic.

Comment: If you are new to Python, you probably shouldn't dive in to `multiprocessing` first.

Answer (score 2):

Move your `print("Starting file")` to inside your script entrypoint.

I'd have to read the source code to really verify, but basically, when you start a `multiprocessing.Process` with some target, the resulting `Process` is going to import the target's module, which causes it to run any code like `import` and free-standing statements, like the `print` statement you have. Since you are creating two processes, each one will execute your `print` statement, resulting in the two extra lines you see.

If I move your `print` to within the `__main__`, this works as you expect:

```
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

def worker1():  
    x=1
    while 1<2:
        print("worker1: "+str(x))
        x=x+1
        sleep(3)

def worker2():   
    x=2
    while 1<2:
        print("worker2: "+str(x))
        x=x+2
        sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting file")
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Output:

```
> python mptest.py
Starting file
worker2: 2
worker1: 1
worker2: 4
worker1: 2
# and so on...
```

---

### A deeper explanation

I'll point out that the reason you're seeing what you're seeing is that you're on a platform that uses `spawn` to start the `multiprocessing` processes, which means Windows and macOS.

From the [`multiprocessing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)

> **spawn**
>
> The parent process starts a fresh Python interpreter process.
> The child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run
> the process object’s `run()` method. In particular, unnecessary file
> descriptors and handles from the parent process will not be inherited.
> Starting a process using this method is rather slow compared to using
> fork or forkserver.
>
> Available on Unix and Windows. The default on Windows and macOS.
>
> **fork**
>
> The parent process uses `os.fork()` to fork the Python interpreter.
> The child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the
> parent process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child
> process. Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is
> problematic.
>
> Available on Unix only. The default on Unix.

If you ran your original code on something like a Linux-based system, you would not see your original issue because it would use `os.fork()` to start the subprocesses, so the children would get a copy of the parent's virtual memory.

```
# On my CentOS system
> python3 mptest.py
Starting file
worker2: 2
worker1: 1
```

However, if I change `multiprocessing` to use `spawn`, by using `multiprocessing.set_start_method`...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # force 'spawn'
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

I get your original issue...

```
# still on my CentOS system, now with 'spawn' mode set
python3 mptest.py
Starting file
Starting file
Starting file
worker2: 2
worker1: 1
```

However, don't rely on that behaviorial difference of spawning vs. forking if you want your `multiprocessing` code to run on more than just your own system.

Comment: so it is also importing "multiprocessing and sleep" three times also. In the same way can I prevent the unnecessary and multiply "import multiprocessing and 
from time import sleep" ?

Comment: @user12647598 Why would you think those are unnecessary imports? They're pivotal to running your code - when multiprocessing creates the subprocesses to run, they're running the targets as scripts in separate processes, so they need to separately do stuff like run `import` statements.

Comment: I was just talking about importing the same thing over and over again. It is important to import only once but I want to avoid importing again and again. Please do advise. Thanks.

Comment: @wkl When `multiprocessing` creates those subprocesses with the `spawn` start method, that is. On Linux, Python defaults to `fork`...

Comment: @user12647598 _Why_ is it important? _Why_ do you want to avoid it?

Comment: So, it is necessary to import all packages like multiprocessing to run  each process/subprocess every time ?

Comment: @user12647598 Depending on your execution environment, how it would operate would be a little different. As @AKX pointed out, on Linux (and most Unix-like systems), python defaults to `os.fork` which would avoid a lot of what you're asking about like the duplicate `import` statements, or the multiple `print` statements, because the forked processes get a copy of the parent process's virtmem. However, on macos and Windows, it `spawn`s which is basically starting the processes up from scratch, which causes all that extra stuff to run. I'll edit more explanation into my answer.